# Rewrite Rule To Detect Numbers Only

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a rewrite rule which will detect numbers only and forward them accordingly. I want the rewrite rule to be ignored if anything but numbers appears.

- `/index.php` - OK
- `/` - OK
- `/42365` - rewrites to `view.php?id=42365`

What I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)?$ view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `?` from the end of the `([0-9]+)` group, which makes it optional. You *must* have numbers for the rewrite to occur:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ view.php?id=$1 [L]
```