# htaccess rewrite to a page that can or cannot have ids

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a htaccess rule to rewrite the following URL's:

```
localhost/abc/def/1 (or with trailing slash would be fine)
```

to

```
localhost/abc/def.php?id=1
```

accessing just 
`localhost/abc/def/` is also valid, and it's working.

My code so far:

```
RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule  ^index$                ./src/index.php    [NC,L] # it works
RewriteRule  ^def/?$                ./src/def.php [NC,L]  #works too!
RewriteRule  ^def/(.*)?$            ./src/def.php?id=$1 [NC,L] #this doesnt
```

I've read some posts like this one [Rewrite Rule To Detect Numbers Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299826/rewrite-rule-to-detect-numbers-only) but they didn't work for me.

The weird thing is, if i change the slash between def and the id part with underline, it does work, like this:

```
RewriteRule  ^def_(.*)?$            ./src/def.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

But the URL becomes `localhost/abc/def_1` and doesnt look that good.

**UPDATE:**
Site structure:

```
/home/username/public_html/abc/  (have multiple websites on public_html)
|_media/
|____js/
|____css/
|____images/
|_src/
|____def.php
|____fgh.php
|_.htaccess
```

When the rule to redirect def/1 does work, the media url's within the page are also being translated to:
`http://localhost/abc/def/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reproducing your case scenario, I've made the follow folder structure:

```
/home/username/public_html/
|_ abc/
|___ .htaccess
|___ src/
|_____ def.php
```

In my `.htaccess` located inside the `abc` folder, I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^def/?$ src/def.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^def/([1-9]+)/?$ src/def.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

And all the scenarios you mentioned work as expected.

These 2 go to `def.php`:

```
domain.com/abc/def
domain.com/abc/def/
```

These 2 go to `def.php?id=1` and `def.php?id=3` respectively:

```
domain.com/abc/def/1
domain.com/abc/def/3/
```

I am afraid you might have additional `.htaccess` or rules taking effect or even your browser cached not giving the proper information you want.

Try using a different browser and try the above exactly as I described it.

Comment: Hi Prix, thanks for replying, indeed it worked, but for example, all images within that page are being translated to localhost/abc/def/... I will include your structure on the post to give you more details... just a sec

Comment: @HelioGabrenha if you use relative path to images i.e.: `images/test.jpg` then yes, because when you have the ending trailing slash it thinks its the higher level directory `def/` so it thinks its `def/images/test.jpg`. Your options there are https://stackoverflow.com/a/3900018/342740

Comment: You are right, fixing the relative paths made everything work.... i never thought it would be that because all other rules to different pages were working perfectly!
Thanks again!

Comment: @HelioGabrenha yw